# Como escribo correctamente la sintaxis de DLookup

Tags: vba, ms-access

Estoy intentando escribir un código que me extraiga el valor de un campo de una tabla uno (asignado a variable) y lo busque con `DLookup` para ver si existe un registro relacionado y almacenar el resultado en una variable 2 pero la instrucción `DLookup` me da error (No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterio: (los campos son idénticos): el código es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub nro_identificacion_LostFocus()
Dim vloc As String, vloc2 As String

vloc = (Me.nro_identificacion)
MsgBox vloc

vloc2 = DLookup("nro_identificacion", "p1", "[nro_identificacion]=" & vloc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, tienes que usar el mismo tipo de dato que el campo `[nro_identificacion]`. En tu código, defines `vloc` como `String` así que entiendo que el campo es tipo Texto.

Lo segundo, la estructura correcta sería:

`vloc2 = DLookup("[nro_identificacion]", "p1", "[nro_identificacion]='" & vloc &"'")`

Se construye como una cláusula WHERE de SQL. Si tu criterio es de texto, la comparación tiene que ir entre comillas simples, por eso hemos puesto `='" & vloc &"'")`. Sin embargo, si cambias el tipo de dato a uno numérico, entonces no habría que poner las comillas.

> Más información: **[Método Application. DLookup
>   (Access)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.application.dlookup)**

Prueba de esta manera y nos cuentas.

Comment: Si eso era , me esta costando ese tipo de nomenclatura , gracias

Comment: @Arturo Fenomenal, prueba la solución y si te funciona, por favor, marca la respuesta como correcta para poder cerrar la pregunta.